# How to create relationships between entities with existing database that does not contain foreign keys

Tags: entity-framework-core, entity-framework-core-2.1

Using Entity Framework Core 2.0

Stuck with company's production database which has primary keys defined for each table but no foreign keys defined for any relationships.

Dependent records in the database have id fields which are intended to relate to the primary key fields of the parent record like you would normally find with a foreign key relationship/constraint. But these fields were all created as INT NOT NULL and are using a SQL default of '0'.

As a result dependent records have been inserted over time without requiring that a related parent record be specified.

Initially I defined my models in EF with integers and used a fluent configuration to specify "IsRequired". This was done so I could run migrations to create a test database for comparison against the production database to verify that my code first was correctly coded.

This then lead to the problem while using "Include" in my Linq queries which performs an inner join that results in dropping the records that contain the 0's in the id fields of the dependent record.

The only way that I have found to make this work is to model all of the id fields in the dependent entity as nullable integers and remove the "IsRequired" from the fluent configuration.

When using the "Include" it performs a left outer join keeping all of the dependent entities. This also means that any reference properties on the included entities are set to null instead of an empty string. This part can probably be fixed fairly easily.

The downside is if I wanted to use migrations to create a database now, all id fields in the dependent records would be created as NULL.

**Is there anyone who has run up against this type of situation? Does anyone have any suggestions to try other than the approach I am using?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't dealt with this scenario before but I wonder if you can solve it by defining the FK property as Nullable and then in the migrations, after the migration is created, edit it to add a HasDefaultValue property to ensure that it's 0? (doc for that migration method: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/relational/default-values)

Comment: I created a nullable id field, added a foreign key data annotation to reference the navigation property. In my configuration object, I used the fluent API to add the 'HasDefaultValueSql' with a value of ('').In the migration file I changed the 'id' to nullable:false and removed the foreign key constraint being added to the table. I left the index that was added for the foreign key since my existing db's table did have indexes for all of the 'id' fields. I tested EF navigation in both directions. Double checked all counts. Left outer joins worked. Thanx, Julie, for putting me on the right track

Comment: that's a lot of trickery. Is it working? Would be interesting to see if you could succeed with less of those tweaks.

Comment: Maybe making migrations conform to the existing db is not a necessary. I thought it should be complete e2e, using EF not only to interact with the current DB but also be able to reproduce it and use migrations going forward to be complete. My thinking maybe skewed considering the current state of this particular db (no identity columns, no FK, etc). In a second attempt I simply made the id field representing the foreign key a int? and then in my type configuration file I used the 'HasDefaultValue' as 0. All CRUD actions perform as expected. Using include produces preferred result of LOJ.

Comment: Since the db is the real issue at hand, I have considered 2 options if apps that are supported by this db are rewritten in newer technologies (VB6 currently).The first is abandoning the original schema, creating a new schema based on requirements of future development while attempting to migrate data of high importance. The second would be to make changes to the existing db data in a safe way that would allow for adding the required constraints. As an additional note the db doesn't have any identity columns, it uses a keys table to keep track of the next primary key for each table in the db.